# Updating A DataGridView Cell Incrementally

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, increment

I'm currently having a slight issue duplicating a row and incrementing the sequence number.

So based on a button click, this is how I'm duplicating row 0, duplicated only one time per click.

```
    Dim dr As DataRow

    For n As Integer = 0 To 0         ' how many dupes you want
        dr = tbl.NewRow
        For c As Integer = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1   ' copy data from 0 to NewRow
            dr.Item(c) = tbl.Rows(0).Item(c)
        Next
        tbl.Rows.Add(dr)            ' add NewRow to datatable
    Next n
```

Here's how I'm creating the sequence number, pads with leading zeros, which seems to increment, but only after I click the duplicate button, so essentially the last row added, it the duplicated row 0, but doesn't represent the new sequence number needed.

```
'UPDATE SEQUENCE NUMBER
    i += 1

    Dim value As Integer = i
    Dim r As Integer

    Dim decimalLength1 As Integer = value.ToString("D").Length + 7
    Dim decimalLength2 As Integer = value.ToString("D").Length + 6
    Dim decimalLength3 As Integer = value.ToString("D").Length + 5
    Dim decimalLength4 As Integer = value.ToString("D").Length + 4

    If i >= 0 And i <= 9 Then
        '1 TO 9 FORMAT
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("sequence")
        DataGridView1.Item(73, r).Value = value.ToString("D" + decimalLength1.ToString())
        'Debug.Print(value.ToString("D" + decimalLength1.ToString()))
    ElseIf i >= 10 And i <= 99 Then
        '10 TO 99 FORMAT
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("sequence")
        DataGridView1.Item(73, r).Value = value.ToString("D" + decimalLength2.ToString())
        'Debug.Print(value.ToString("D" + decimalLength1.ToString()))
    ElseIf i >= 100 And i <= 999 Then
        '100 TO 999 FORMAT
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("sequence")
        DataGridView1.Item(73, r).Value = value.ToString("D" + decimalLength3.ToString())
        'Debug.Print(value.ToString("D" + decimalLength1.ToString()))
    ElseIf i >= 1000 And i <= 9999 Then
        '1000 TO 9999 FORMAT
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("sequence")
        DataGridView1.Item(73, r).Value = value.ToString("D" + decimalLength4.ToString())
        'Debug.Print(value.ToString("D" + decimalLength1.ToString()))
    End If
```

Row 0 will always have a sequence number of 1, so in theory I need to start incrementing at 2.

Suggestions? Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this?

**UPDATE 2**

```
    Dim startSeq As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows(0).Item(73))

    MsgBox("startSeq = " & startSeq)

    For n As Integer = 0 To NumericUpDown1.Value - 1

        MsgBox("n = " & n)

        dr = tbl.NewRow

        For c As Integer = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1

            dr.Item(c) = tbl.Rows(0).Item(c)

            If c = "73" Then     ' if this is the SEQ column,
                ' add the current seq val to the seq column
                dr.Item(c) = (startSeq + n).ToString("00000000")
            End If
        Next c
        tbl.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next n
```

Comment: can you give an example of the desired output/format?  Also cant you start with sequence value of the original row and create the new sequence value *as* you create the duplicates?

Comment: Well that was another issue I had, starting with a sequence number of 2 vs 1, who knows what I was doing.

Comment: Desired output should be 00000001, 00000002, 00000003, etc. I have the format part correct, in padding leading zeros though.

Comment: do the rows you duplicate always start with 0?

Comment: I could duplicated row 0, or duplicate the last row and increment the number, either or would work.

Comment: this is the thing with 1 row ever but lots of columns, right?  in that case row(0) is fine  (sorry, I forgot the back story).

Comment: what are you doing, adding one row at a time on a button click?  the new `DuplicateRows` was meant to create them all at once...perhaps get a value from the user for how many to add (or calculate it - no idea where the value comes from).  Adding one at a time is more problematic.  Please clarify the add X number of rows process.

Comment: hmmm, ok let me think about this. i could return an input box and duplicate based on that.

Comment: at least you can use `ToString` to get rid of that long nasty block.  use a `NumericUpDown` or text control, not an `InputBox` or you may have conversion issues.

Comment: check out the update part 1, is that ok to use? if so, now to figure out the duplication and sequencer and how to incorporate.

Comment: looks ok, so far - how do you determine which column has the sequence?  By name?  The only part that is missing is the part in my answer that adds the sequence string as they are created....`dr.Item(c) = (startSeq + n).ToString("00000000")` which I thought was the crux of your question

Comment: column named "sequence" is where the incremented number needs to go

Comment: Somewhere, like when the data is imported, I would store the column index of that special column.  In your button click, you could call the `DuplicateRows` function. `ColIndx` is the index of that column, `Dupes` would be `NumericUpDown1.Value - 1` - it should add the rows with the sequence value

Comment: do i need to worry about when calling the function i get a warning? function 'duplicaterows' doesnt return a value on all code paths.

Comment: simply use call duplicaterows()? i use that and return errors saying argument not specified for parameter...

Comment: You said the columns change around from time to time.  `DuplicateRows(int, int)` takes 2 integers.  The first is the ColumnIndex of the sequence column for this session.  The second is the number to add.  If you dont like invoking a method and passing parameters, use it in the button press.

Comment: no clue what im doing wrong, cant call the sub within the button click. i appreciate the help but i need to take a step back.

Comment: then move the code to the click - it is almost identical to your **Update** code except for the part that adds the sequence string for each row as they are added.  I suspect you havent initialized the column index variable in trying to call it.

Comment: ok, finally, i got something actually working correctly, however, once i duplicate the record 1 time, my second record still has a sequence of 1, not 2. what am i missing?

Comment: ooops, nevermind. i added "+ 1" so it reads (startseq + n + 1). this seems to be working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to add the sequencer as you create the duplicates.  Perhaps make it a method and pass the index of the column which has the sequence string.  Something like:

```
Private Sub DuplicateRows(ColIndx As Integer,
                Dupes As Integer)

    ' start value is Row(0) + 1
    Dim startSeq As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows(0).Item(ColIndx )) + 1

    For n As Integer = 0 to Dupes -1
        dr = tbl.NewRow

        For c As Integer = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
             If c = ColIndx Then     ' if this is the SEQ column,
                ' add the current seq val to the seq column
               dr.Item(c) = (startSeq + n).ToString("00000000")
           Else
               ' otherwise copy the data from Row(0)
               dr.Item(c) = tbl.Rows(0).Item(c) 
           End If
        Next c
        tbl.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next n
End Sub
```

This should initialize each new row with an incremented counter.  `Is there a better/cleaner way of doing this`

a) you should be adding to the `DataTable`, not the DGV if it is bound

b) `(startSeq + n).ToString("00000000")` should work to do the padding etc instead of that ugly block of code.

c) Use `Option Strict On`.  `If c = "73" ...` is nonsense which makes the compiler guess at your intentions.  Its is bug food.

d) Hardcoding "73" may work *this* time, but previously you said it could be anywhere.  The code below finds the sequence column based on the name so it can appear anywhere. Rather than a form level var, you could find it just before you make the dupes or even in the Dupes procedure.

e) `Dim startSeq As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(tbl.Rows(0).Item(73))` if you examine the answer above, this should be `... + 1` to increment the first value.

---

#### Usage:

```
Private tbl As DataTable             ' table loaded from flat file
Private SeqColIndex As Integer       ' assigned somewhere to
                                   ' point to the "sequence" column

' method to load data
Dim connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;..."
Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connstr)
  ...
End Using

' FIND the sequence column for this session
For n = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
    If tbl.Columns(n).ColumnName.ToLowerInvariant = "sequence" Then
        SeqColIndex = n
        Exit For
    End If
Next

' later to add some rows
Private Sub ButtonAddRow_Click(...

    DuplicateRows(SeqColIndex, NumericUpDown1.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the DUPES_TO_ADD? Is that the function being declared?

Comment: I changed that from yours because you had `For n As Integer = 0 To 0` which doesnt actually add as many as you want. `DuplicateRows` receives it as a param

Comment: I guess I'm not quite understanding what you did...let me look over this a little further.

Comment: `DuplicateRows` will add the sequence value in the same loop as when the rows are duplicated

Comment: I still dont get where and what DUPES_TO_ADD is referencing. My apologizes.

Comment: I'll post what I have currently, doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: I need to leave this for awhile. I got myself so lost with this, especially now that not duplicating per click and the newest code you posted.